# angular 2 remembers my error no matter what i do

Tags: angular

I had an error on Angular2.
I needed to restart my pc, and then came back later to the project, and no matter what- the error keeps showing!

I deleted all the code, even went and deleted the `"<my-app>Loading...</my-app>"` snippet of code from my index.html, the error is still there.

the error is :

```
nhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'alert' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    </div>

  <div class="alert valign center-align" [ERROR ->][alert]="alert" *ngIf="alert">Please Provide Title and Text</div>
    "): AppComponent@17:41 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'alert' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    </div>

  <div class="alert valign center-align" [ERROR ->][alert]="alert" *ngIf="alert">Please Provide Title and Text</div>
```

(cleared cache as well..)

any idea what it could be ?

Comment: That would help us if you told us what the error is.

Comment: @StephaneM thanks, edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder and running...

```
npm install
```

It could help as something may have happened to your packages.

Or you must have a div that has the 'alert' attribute on it. Try removing that attribute.

Comment: i did that, and it still shows. also, I deleted the alert attribute (and even removed the app tag from my index.html

Comment: What happens if you remove the whole div that has the 'alert' on it? Also try removing the ngIf, then if it renders we can start adding the bits back in and see if we can isolate exactly what the issue is.

Comment: that's what I did.
basically I removed the whole <my-app> tag all together

Comment: Yes I see, but what happens if you leave all the code in there but just remove the divs that have the 'alert' on it? I think we need to break things down to work it out.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `alert` is not a native property of the `div` tag.
You can either use a `Directive` to add properties, or if you really just want to fill the attribute, use the proper binding like so:

```
[attr.alert]="alert"
```